# collecting SQL statements using Excel

Tags: sql, excel, select, insert

in my everyday work, I am receiving data in Excel spreadsheets, which I need to insert into relational database.

To accomplish this, I prepare formulas which generate "insert" statement (I am using both **insert** and **select** statement for example to choose ID of all elements with specific label).

Because those spreadsheets are complex, they contain SQL commands in more than one column.
This is the point where problems begin - I cannot simply select all cells, copy them and paste into SQL Server (it will concatenate information from cells in the same row).
In most cases I'm preparing additional sheet where I'm collecting all statements in one column
(using simply formula which rewrite text from other cells). Unfortunately preparing such sheet is time consuming and might causing an error (for example if I forgot about column or I add rows).

Is there any more convenient way to do it?

I thought about writing a macro which collect all values from selected range.

Is it good idea or can I use something better?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that using [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

You know what are the rules so you have the business logic in your head. Now, just type the code to do it :)

If you want you can do the insert in the Excel using something like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819).